# Difficulty transforming a product of factorials into a sum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, factorial

I want to prove this relation which I know is true for even n's
$${{{\rm 2}^{{\it n}}\cdot{\rm (}{\it n}{\rm !)}^{{\rm 2}}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it n}{\rm )!}}}\times{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{{{\it n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}\times\left[{{\rm 2}\times{\rm 4}\times\cdots\times{\it n}}\right]\times\left[{{\rm (}{\it n}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it n}+{\rm 3}{\rm )}\cdots\times{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it n}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right]}\over{{\it n}{\rm !}}}={\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{{{{\it n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}\times\left[{\left({{\it n}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}}\right)\cdots{\rm (}{\it n}-{\rm 4}{\rm )(}{\it n}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it n}}\right]\left[{{\rm (}{\it n}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it n}+{\rm 3}{\rm )}\cdots\left({{\it n}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}$$
I came across this formula in a textbook. I know this is true for all even positive integers n. For example, for n=4, the left side of equality is:
$${{2^{4}\cdot (4!)^{2}}\over{8!}}\times{{(-1)^{2}\times (2\times 4)\times (5\times 7)}\over{4!}}={{8}\over{3}}$$
and the right side is:
$$1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2}{{{(-1)^{k}\left[{\left({4-(2k-2)}\right)\times\cdots\times (4-2)\times 4}\right]\times\left[{(4+1)(4+3)\cdots (4+(2k-1))}\right]}\over{(2k)!}}}=1+{{(-1)\times 4\times 5}\over{2!}}+{{(-1)^{2}\times 2\times 4\times 5\times 7}\over{4!}}=1-10+{{35}\over{3}}{{35-27}\over{3}}={{8}\over{3}}$$
as you can see it's true for n=4.

Edit: I used induction to prove this formula. As said before, we know that this relation is true for even n's, so first we show that the relationship is true for n=2. for n=2 the left side is
$${{2^{2}\times (2!)^{2}}\over{4!}}\times{{(-1)\times 2\times 3}\over{2!}}=-2$$
and the right side is
$$1+{{(-1)\times 2\times 3}\over{2!}}=1-3=-2$$
so it's true for n=2. Now, we assume that the relation is true for an arbitrary even number n, that is
$${{{\rm 2}^{{\it n}}\cdot{\rm (}{\it n}{\rm !)}^{{\rm 2}}}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it n}{\rm )!}}}\times{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{{{\it n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}\times\left[{{\rm 2}\times{\rm 4}\times\cdots\times{\it n}}\right]\times\left[{{\rm (}{\it n}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it n}+{\rm 3}{\rm )}\cdots\times{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it n}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right]}\over{{\it n}{\rm !}}}={\rm 1}+\sum\limits_{{\it k}{\rm =1}}^{{{{\it n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\it k}}\times\left[{\left({{\it n}-{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}}\right)\cdots{\rm (}{\it n}-{\rm 4}{\rm )(}{\it n}-{\rm 2}{\rm )}{\it n}}\right]\left[{{\rm (}{\it n}+{\rm 1}{\rm )(}{\it n}+{\rm 3}{\rm )}\cdots\left({{\it n}+{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}-{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2}{\it k}{\rm )!}}}}$$
And we try to show that the relation is also true for n+2, that is, to prove that
$${{{\rm 2}^{{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}}{\rm \cdot}{\rm ((n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)!)}^{{\rm 2}}}\over{{\rm (2(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2))!}}}{\rm \times}{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{{{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3}{\rm )(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm (2n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)}}\right]}\over{{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm !}}}{\rm =}{\rm 1}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -}{\rm 4)n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
or
$${{{\rm 2}^{{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}}{\rm \cdot}{\rm ((n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)!)}^{{\rm 2}}}\over{{\rm (2(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2))!}}}{\rm \times}{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{{{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3}{\rm )(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm (2n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)}}\right]}\over{{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}{\rm !}}}{\rm =}{\rm 1}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -4}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -}{\rm 4)n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm +}{\rm 1)}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
Second Edit: Using the relation ${{{\rm 2}^{{\rm n}}{\rm \cdot}{\left({{\rm n!}}\right)}^{{\rm 2}}}\over{{\rm (2n)!n!}}}{\rm =}{{{\rm 1}}\over{{\rm (2n-1)!!}}}$ that FShrike suggested, the desired relation is rewritten in a simpler form as follows:
$${{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm n}}\right]}\over{{\rm 1*3*...*(n-3)*(n-1)}}}{\rm =1+}\sum\limits_{{\rm k=1}}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (}{\rm 2k}{\rm -}{\rm 2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (}{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm 2}{\rm )n}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 1)(}{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm 3}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (}{\rm 2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (}{\rm 2k}{\rm )!}}}}$$
and we want to conclude the following relationship from it:
$${{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}{\rm +1}}{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]}\over{{\rm 1*3*...*(n}{\rm +}{\rm 1)}}}{\rm =1+}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -4}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
By comparing the sides of the last two relations, we come to the conclusion that we must multiply the sides of the first relation by ${\rm -}{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm n+1}}}$. This yields:
$${{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}{\rm +1}}{\rm \times}\left[{{\rm 2}{\rm \times}{\rm 4}{\rm \times}{\rm \cdots}{\rm \times}{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]}\over{{\rm 1*3*...*(n}{\rm +}{\rm 1)}}}{\rm =-}{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm n+1}}}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
The left side of the relationship is correct. Now we have to change the right side so that it fits into the desired form. So now we must prove
$${\rm 1+}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -4}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$
$${\rm =-}{{{\rm n+2}}\over{{\rm n+1}}}{\rm +}\sum\limits_{{\rm k}{\rm =}{\rm 1}}^{{{{\rm n}}\over{{\rm 2}}}}{{{{\rm (}{\rm -}{\rm 1)}^{{\rm k}{\rm +}{\rm 1}}{\rm \times}\left[{\left({{\rm n}{\rm -}{\rm (2k}{\rm -2}{\rm )}}\right){\rm \cdots}{\rm (n}{\rm -2}{\rm )n(n}{\rm +}{\rm 2)}}\right]\left[{{\rm (n}{\rm +}{\rm 3)(n}{\rm +}{\rm 5}{\rm )}{\rm \cdots}\left({{\rm n}{\rm +}{\rm (2k}{\rm -}{\rm 1}{\rm )}}\right)}\right]}\over{{\rm (2k)!}}}}$$

Comment: What has this question to do with [tag:problem-solving]?

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Well, this is a problem isnt it? Please guide me. What title do you think is appropriate? I did not find a suitable title

Comment: I only wrote about the tags, not about the title. And that [tag:problem-solving] tag description says “Use this tag when you want to determine the thinking that is needed to solve a certain type of problem, as opposed to looking for a specific answer to a question.” Isn't this exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @jjagmath  I changed the title. Is it better now?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I removed the tag. What tag is suitable here? What do you recommend for it?

Comment: The [tag:proof-writing] and [tag:relations] tags are also inappropriate. I suggest [tag:induction] and [tag:algebra-precalculus].

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I followed your suggestion. btw Do you have any idea about the answer to my question? I really need the answer

Comment: Hi absolute zero. I’m sorry about all the downvotes. They would have been avoided if you explained your thoughts more, and showed your attempt at induction. It doesn’t matter if the attempt failed, we still want to see it, for a variety of reasons. I can get you going by pointing out: $$\frac{2^n(n!)^2}{(2n)!\cdot n!}=\frac{1}{(2n-1)!!}$$With the double factorial. You figure that out by cancelling the $n!$ and carefully paying attention to what: $$2^n n!=2\times 2\times\cdots\times2\times n\times(n-1)\cdots\times1$$ looks like if you fully expand it. That help to start

Comment: @absolutezero Nope. Try something that involve words like "sum" and "factorial". You wrote "prove a  mathematical relationship" which could be referring to a problem in Geometry, or Algebraic Topology, or Analytic Number Theory, or ...

Comment: @FShrike  Oh thank you very much. I edited the question a bit and am working on it again. If I encounter a problem, I will ask you again. Let's see what can I do

Comment: I’ve edited in a provisional title, which is more accurate. Describing the problem well in the title is important as @jjagmath says

Comment: I’m also observing that your LaTex is full of unnecessary `\rm`s. The standard text, e.g. `1+2`, will render just fine without it, and it is much, much easier to type!

Comment: @FShrike I used the relation you suggested in the second edit and I have almost reached the result, but in the end I ran into a problem: The right side is different from what I want

Comment: @FShrike I think I must use induction for the last equality. Am I in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Often it is convenient to try to simplify identities at first. Since $n$ is assumed to be an even non-negative integer we will take $n=2m$ in the following. We show OPs claimed identity is equivalent to show
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{4m-2k}{2m}\binom{2m}{k}=4^m\qquad\qquad m\geq 0}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
which might also be an interesting starting point to prove the identity.

In order to do the transformations we use factorials, double-factorials, binomial coefficients and a relationship between even and odd double factorials.
\begin{align*}
m!&=m\cdot(m-1)\cdots3\cdot2\cdot 1\tag{2.1}\\
(2m)!!&=(2m)(2m-2)\cdots 6\cdot4\cdot2=2^m\cdot m!\tag{2.2}\\
(2m-1)!!&=(2m-1)(2m-3)\cdots 5\cdot 3\cdot 1=\frac{(2m)!}{(2m)!!}=\frac{(2m)!}{2^mm!}\tag{2.3}\\
\binom{m}{k}&=\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}\tag{2.4}
\end{align*}

We start with OPs left-hand side and obtain
\begin{align*}
&\frac{2^{2m}(2m)!(2m)!}{(4m)!}(-1)^m\frac{(2m)!!}{(2m)!}\,\frac{(4m-1)!!}{(2m-1)!!}\tag{$\to\ (2.2),(2.3)$}\\
&\qquad=\frac{2^{2m}(2m)!(2m)!}{(4m)!}(-1)^m\frac{2^mm!}{(2m)!}\,\frac{(4m)!}{2^{2m}(2m)!}\,\frac{2^mm!}{(2m)!}\tag{$\to\ (2.3)$}\\
&\qquad=(-1)^m2^{2m}\frac{(m!)^2}{(2m)!}\tag{$\to\ $cancellation}\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^m4^m\binom{2m}{m}^{-1}}\tag{$\to\ (2.4)$}
\end{align*}

Simplification of OPs right-hand side gives
\begin{align*}
&1+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\,\frac{(2m)!!}{(2m-2k)!!}\,\frac{(2m+2k-1)!!}{(2m-1)!!}\tag{$\to\ (2.2),(2.3)$}\\
&\quad=1+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\,\frac{2^mm!}{2^{m-k}(m-k)!}\,\frac{(2m+2k)!}{2^{m+k}(m+k)!}\,\frac{2^mm!}{(2m)!}\tag{$\to\ (2.2),(2.3)$}\\
&\quad=1+\binom{2m}{m}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}\,\frac{(2m+2k)!}{(m-k)!(m+k)!}\tag{$\to\ (2.4)$, cancellation}\\
&\quad\,\,\color{blue}{=1+\binom{2m}{m}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^k\binom{2m+2k}{2k}\binom{2m}{m+k}}\tag{$\to \ (2.4)$}
\end{align*}

> Equating the blue colored lines which we derived from OPs left-hand and right-hand side, we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> (-1)^m4^m\binom{2m}{m}^{-1}&=1+\binom{2m}{m}^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^k\binom{2m+2k}{2k}\binom{2m}{m+k}\\
> (-1)^m4^m&=\binom{2m}{m}+\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^k\binom{2m+2k}{2k}\binom{2m}{m+k}\tag{4.1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{2m+2k}{2k}\binom{2m}{m+k}\tag{4.2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{m-k}\binom{4m-2k}{2m-2k}\binom{2m}{2m-k}\tag{4.3}\\
> \color{blue}{4^m}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^{k}\binom{4m-2k}{2m}\binom{2m}{k}}\tag{4.4}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (4.1) we multiply with $\binom{2m}{m}$.
- In (4.2) we can merge $1$ into the sum by starting with $k=0$.
- in (4.3) we change the order of summation $k\to m-k$.
- In (4.4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$ twice and multiply with $(-1)^m$.